# Adding/removing class with D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

The following two questions have more to do with CSS than with D3.

```js
let svg = d3.select('body')
            .append('svg');
svg.append('circle')
   .attr('cx', 100)
   .attr('cy', 100)
   .attr('r', 50)
   .attr('class', ball)
   .on('mouseenter', function() {
       d3.select(this)
         .classed('over', true);
   });
```

```css
circle.ball {
    fill: blue;
}
circle.ball over {
    fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If in the code above I write

```
circle {
    fill: blue;
}
```

instead of

```
circle.ball {
    fill: blue;
}
```

then the circle is initially filled blue. Why is setting the class to `ball` not affecting the fill?

I'm aware of the `:hover` CSS option. In the following I'd like to effect a change using the `mouseenter` event and a class setting. When the event is triggered, an additional class `over` adjusts the `fill`. Why does inserting the additional class not affect the fill?

Specifically, is `circle.ball over` the right specification to say "applies only when the two classes `ball` and `over` are simultaneously present for a circle"?

(The symmetric case for mouse exit, along with setting `.classed('over', false)`, is omitted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code, first you forgot to add quotes to `.attr('class', ball)` and the second one is that you have the hover selector `circle.ball over` set in the wrong way it should be `circle.ball.over` since the over class is on circle not on one of its children, here is a working snippet:

```js
let svg = d3.select('body')
            .append('svg');
svg.append('circle')
   .attr('cx', 100)
   .attr('cy', 100)
   .attr('r', 50)
   .attr('class', 'ball')
   .on('mouseenter', function(d) {
       console.log('asdasd');
       d3.select(this)
         .classed('over', true);
   });
```

```css
circle.ball {
    fill: blue;
}
circle.ball.over {
    fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just a problem while stting class attribute set it as string not object 
`.attr('class', "ball")` instead `.attr('class', ball)`
also in css you're mistaking in over , in css its written as pseudo attr like `:hover`

see below working snippet

```js
let svg = d3.select('body')
            .append('svg');
svg.append('circle')
   .attr('cx', 100)
   .attr('cy', 100)
   .attr('r', 50)
   .attr('class', "ball")
   .on('mouseenter', function() {
       d3.select(this)
         .classed('over', true);
   });
```

```css
circle.ball {
    fill: blue;
}
circle.ball:hover {
    fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```